# x86 target not running on 32 bit Windows XP

Tags: .net, windows, x86, 64-bit

I have a .NET application that uses MS Access as a database. I have been using the AnyCPU as the compile target. This has been running well on Windows XP 32bit. Now I need to deploy to Windows 7 64bit. When I first deployed, the database connection failed. So I found that I need to change the compile target to x86 to force Windows 7 64bit to run the program in 32bit mode. This worked well. But when I tried to run the program on Windows XP 32bit, it fails.

I rather confused, could someone point me in the direction of how to resolve this?

EDIT:

Here are the error details from ClickOnce on the Windows XP machine and the compile target is x86:

ERROR DETAILS

```
   Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [2/10/2011 10:29:44 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (SubscriptionState)
        - The deployment identity does not match the subscription.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.CheckUpdateInManifest(SubscriptionState subState, Uri updateCodebaseUri, AssemblyManifest deployment, Version currentVersion, Boolean& bUpdateInPKTGroup)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentUpdate(SubscriptionState& subState, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ProcessOrFollowShortcut(String shortcutFile, String& errorPageUrl, TempFile& deployFile)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
```

Comment: what is the failure (behavior, exception, error message, error code) that you get when running on XP 32-bit?

Comment: /platform anycpu switch generates PE32/agnostic managed module which should run on x86 and x64 windows. 64 bit windows provides WOW64 technology that can run 32 bit apps. Do you know the exact reason for db connection failure? And yes with /platform x64, the app will not run on x86.

Comment: Any CPU should work ... Do you have unmanaged component in your solution .. It will need to be compiled for both x86 and x64 seperately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was that after I changed from "AnyCPU" to "x86", the update failed because of the identity error. I had to uninstall the old version. After that the program installed and ran successfully.

@Chris Schmich - Thanks for pointing me to the details of the error.